# DMin Won't Read First Column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Sub in Access 2010 that's supposed to pull the lowest value between three columns. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be reading the first column. I've checked the spelling a thousand times, and I have no idea what else could possibly wrong. Any suggestions would be beyond appreciated.

```
Private Sub UpdatePriority_Click()

Const Superior As Long = 9999

Dim MinGeoPri As Variant
Dim MinStrPri As Variant
Dim MinSOPri As Variant

MinGeoPri = Nz(DMin("[GeoPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)
MinStrPri = Nz(DMin("[StrPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)
MinSOPri = Nz(DMin("[SOPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = Activity.ProjNo"), Superior)

Overall_Priority.Requery

Overall_Priority = IIf(((IIf([MinStrPri] < [MinGeoPri], [MinStrPri], [MinGeoPri]))) < [MinSOPri], ((IIf([MinStrPri] < [MinGeoPri], [MinStrPri], [MinGeoPri]))), [MinSOPri])

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1) I don't know where `Activity.ProjNo` comes from, but the DMin calls should probably read:

```
DMin("[GeoPri]", "[Projects]", "Projects.ProjNo = " & Activity.ProjNo)
```

with the parameter outside of the WHERE string.

2) What is `Overall_Priority.Requery` supposed to do, if you set the same (field? variable?) right afterwards?

3) Your IIf statement is a nightmare, I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the parentheses. :)
Much better: use a VBA Min() function as found here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/132404-max-min-visual-basic-applications.html

```
Public Function Min(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Variant

   Dim minValue As Variant, Value As Variant
   minValue = values(0)
   For Each Value In values
       If Value < minValue Then minValue = Value
   Next
   Min = minValue

End Function
```

ParamArray is great for this sort of thing (unknown number of parameters).

And then:

```
Overall_Priority = Min(MinGeoPri, MinStrPri, MinSOPri)
```

Edit: test function

```
Public Sub MyMinTest()

    Debug.Print Min(47, 11, 88)

End Sub
```

Comment: Requery is supposed to allow the priority field to be re-updated. I tried it using the Min function, but it keeps returning a priority of 0, even if all the fields are filled in (which they often won't be, but for testing purposes I filled them in).

Comment: In the Immediate window, execute this: `? Min(47,11,88)` . My result is 11. Yours?

Comment: Did you copy the `Public Function Min` as written above into a standard module? I can see no reason why it wouldn't work. Which line is highlighted as error?

Comment: I did. It isn't highlighting anything, it's just coming up as a pop-up.

Comment: I tried this and nothing isn't being highlighted, even though the same pop-up keeps coming. It's saying `Sub of Function not defined`, even though I added that Min function.

Comment: Add the call to your code, see Edit above. Then compile, or run MyMinTest()

Comment: It keeps giving me a compile error. I've run the compiler multiple times, and nothing is coming up.